# How to use Github Desktop on Windows VM

Tags: windows, github, virtual-machine, github-enterprise

I am having trouble logging into my GitHub Enterprise account using GitHub Desktop on my Windows VM using VirtualBox. Every time I put in my login details it says "Cannot connect to Host: Failed to connect to host or the host isn't a GitHub Enterprise server". But when I log into GitHub on Firefox using the exact same details it works. I have double checked the server address and it is correct.

I'm not sure if I need to use a virtual appliance version of Github Enterprise, but from what I can find they have discontinued it for VirtualBox.
https://help.github.com/enterprise/11.10.340/admin/articles/getting-started-with-virtualbox/

On my actual machine (not the VM) I can log into my GitHub Enterprise account using GitHub Desktop no problem. Think it might be a VM issue but I am not sure.

Has anyone else been able to get GitHub Desktop working on their windows VM? Was it using a GitHub or GitHub Enterprise account, or should their be any difference in logging in?

Comment: Hi Catherine,
I wonder which type av set up are using for the networkcard?
is it bridged networking/Internal networking/host-only networking etc..?

Comment: @DanielElmnas I have two Network Adapters, a Host-only connection and a NAT connection. I don't understand why I can log into my account vis the Firefox browser on the VM but have trouble with GitHub Desktop.

Comment: What happens if you test bridged connections ?

Comment: @DanielElmnas I still get the same error if I turn on Bridged adapter